# how to retrieve int from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
 private void updateScoreBreaker(){
    DBref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Gamelevel);
    Query maxScore =DBref.orderByChild(SCORE).limitToLast(1);
    maxScore.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         maxScoreLevel=Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.child(SCORE).getValue(String.class));
              maxScoreName=dataSnapshot.getKey();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

i have this error : 
Cannot find local variable 'maxScoreLevel'

Comment: Put "int" in front of maxScoreLevel to declare it, as you have to do with all variables in Java?

Comment: Have you declare `maxScoreLevel` variable? Btw, it's not a Firebase problem :|

Comment: yes i already declared and steel not working

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you haven't declared **maxScoreLevel**. You should declare it as a attribute of the class, so you can change it's value from the ValueEventListener.

```
class something {
    ...
    Integer maxScoreLevel;
    String maxScoreName;
    ...

    private void updateScoreBreaker() {
        DBref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Gamelevel);
        Query maxScore = DBref.orderByChild(SCORE).limitToLast(1);
        maxScore.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                maxScoreLevel = dataSnapshot.child(SCORE).getValue(Integer.class);
                maxScoreName = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If corresponding reference does not exist or has no value, maxScoreLevel will be assigned with *null* value